# Real projective space and the fundamental group

Tags: algebraic-topology

The question is as follows:

(a) Compute the fundamental groups of $\mathbb{R}P^2 \vee \mathbb{R}P^2$ and $\mathbb{R}P^2 \times \mathbb{R}P^2 $.

(b) Show the $\mathbb{R}P^2 \vee \mathbb{R}P^2 $ is not a retract of $ \mathbb{R}P^2 \times \mathbb{R}P^2 $

(c) Show that any map $f: \mathbb{R}P^2 \vee \mathbb{R}P^2 \rightarrow  S^1$ is null-homotopic.

My work so far:

$(a)$ I know how to compute the fundamental group of $\mathbb{R}P^2$. Do I just take products and wedges of that?

$(b)$ It is not going to be a retract because their fundamental groups are not homeomorphic.

$(c)$ I'm not sure how to approach this one. Do I have to make use of covering space theory?

Are my answers and intuitions correct? I just want to know if I'm on the right path. I especially need assistance with part(c)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Community I made a few changes.

Comment: Even after your edits, you are still asking three questions in one. I think it is reasonable to combine (a) and (b) as one proof-verification question, but you should ask (c) separately.

Comment: "I know how to compute the fundamental group of $\mathbb{RP}^2$. Do I just take products and wedges of that?" What does it mean to take wedges of groups?

Comment: a) For the wedge product of spaces, you can use Van Kampen's Thm; for the cartesian product, there is a well-known property of fundamental group that gives you the answer directly (as you suggested, the product of two groups). b) It makes sense to say that two groups are isomorphic (not homeomorphic). The map induced by the retraction should be surjective and the inclusion should be injective. To prove the non-existence, it suffices to consider the group homomorphisms. c) Yes, you need covering space and lifting property to construct a homotopy.

Answer (score 1):

$a)$ For wedge you can use Van Kampen as suggested in the comment, by taking U to be $\mathbb RP^2\vee$ (a contractible nbd of base point ) and similarly take another path connected open set V, and then show that the fundamental group is $\mathbb Z_2*\mathbb Z_2$ and for product you are correct.

$b)$ show that the inclusion can't be injective or the map induced by the retraction can't be surjective (both are trivial)

$c)$ here you need to use lifting criterion, since $f_*(\pi_1(\mathbb RP^2\vee\mathbb RP^2))$ trivial so you can lift $f$ to $\mathbb R$ and hence it's null homotopic.